# How to break a line in a function definition in Python according to pep8?

Tags: python, pep8

I have the following line of code that is just over the limit of 79 characters:

```
def ReportResults(self, intTestID, startTime, stopTime, version, serverType):
```

How do I break the line in the correct way according to pep8?

Comment: A quick skim of PEP-8 would answer your question, wouldn't it? Take a look at the examples in the [indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) section.

Comment: As long as you are concerned about PEP8, you shouldnt capitalize function names, and you should use `snake_case`

Comment: We want to follow pep8 strictly, but we are actually using Python within TestComplete to perform GUI testing, and some implementations in their product uses capitalized function names, so we decided to use hat pattern as well to not confuse ourselves more than enough :)

Comment: There are not enough examples for correct and not correct cases in `indentation` paragraph. What if a developer left a closed bracket on a new line?
I think it's a violation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> The Python standard library is conservative and requires limiting lines to 79 characters (and docstrings/comments to 72).

This is in my opinion the main rule to observe.

Besides this rule, PEP8 recommends aligning brackets, so I would do something like this:

```py
def report_results(self,
                   intTestID,
                   startTime,
                   stopTime,
                   version,
                   serverType):
    pass
```

Note that I renamed your method `report_results`, following the recommended lower_case_with_underscores. Also, notice that the indentation should be aligned with the first letter of the first parameter and not the parenthesis.

Comment: I really wish we could use Haskell-style commas for lists like this, but I agree that this is the best way to go about it in Python. Either everything on one line or each item on its own line.

Comment: But ... mixedCase isn't recommended for functions. It's [`lower_case_with_underscores`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names).

Comment: A true pitty they opted for such a horrendous style of writing big walls of whitespace everywhere. Sure, indentation style preferences are as subjective as it gets but looking at your code like it is some sort of hole cheese seems like anything but desireable.

Answer (score 0):

79 characters is [more of a guideline than a rule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

> Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the nominal line length from 80 to 100 characters (effectively increasing the maximum length to 99 characters), provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at 72 characters.

Additionally, that line is only 77 characters long, so you should be fine anyway. However, if you'd like to break it up, you can use implicit continuation:

```
def ReportResults(self,
                  intTestID,
                  startTime,
                  stopTime,
                  version,
                  serverType):
```

If you have a function signature that goes far past the character limit you're using, that is an indication that the function has too many parameters.